# Является ли объект экземпляром класса? (Бинарные файлы)

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток.
Вопрос заключается в том, что есть какой-то бинарный файл, в который по очереди записываются объекты данного класса ( классов 3 и более ). Каким образом можно считать данные из файла и привести к одному из классов? При условии, что мы не знаем в каком файле записаны какие объекты классов.

Comment: "мы не знаем в каком файле записаны какие" - придется узнать. Читайте в массив байтов или поток и анализируйте.

Comment: И что значит "записываются объекты класса"? Как пишем, так и читаем. А перед данными для каждого объекта - маркер типа.

Comment: ... и размер данных для объекта, чтобы можно было пропустить в случае чего.

Comment: тут подробно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/659537/198316