# У меня есть файл, как узнать что в нем?

Tags: файлы, faq

Начали появляться вопросы подобного типа, обычно связанные с сериализацией. Считаю необходимым разместить подробный ответ на эту тему, чтобы не плодить однотипные ответы и комментарии к вопросам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ок, что мы можем знать про файл?

- имя
- ожидаемую внутреннюю структуру

**1. Допустим мы знаем только имя файла**

У файла всегда есть имя, иногда это имя может не отображаться стандартными средствами, в силу своей специфичности, например .config не будет отображаться в проводнике Windows при включенной опции "скрывать зарегистрированные типы файлов".

Существует также понятие "полное имя", которое задается как сочетание пути (перечисление промежуточных папок) и собственно имени файла.

Само по себе имя дает информации о файле не больше чем имя незнакомого человека, которого вы ни разу не видели. Имя файла позволяет только отличить один файл от другого и использовать это имя вместо физического адреса на диске.

В первом примере был упомянут "тип файла", а что это такое? Тип файла, или расширение имени, это искусственная конструкция, в общем случае, не имеющая ни чего общего с реальным типом файла. Ближайшая аналогия - фамилия человека, по идее она должна говорить о принадлежности к определенной семье, но если собрать всех однофамильцев - то найти у них общего предка скорее всего не удастся. Расширение имени изначально - точка и три буквы после имени файла (.exe, .bat). В настоящее время, ограничений на длину расширения практически нет и существуют составные расширения (.FB2.ZIP, .TAR.GZ), в основном такие расширения у различных архивов. Кроме того, точку можно использовать как часть основного имени.

Какое расширение у файла с абсолютно корректным именем: `I.big.file.with.long.name`?

Ответ: какой угодно, от `*.name` до `*.big.file.with.long.name`, но Windows опознает только `*.name`, т.к. исторически получает тип, путем выборки символов из имени с права до первой точки.

Основное назначение этой части имени - подсказать системе, какой значок на нем рисовать и какую программу запустить, когда вместо явного запуска программы мы "запускаем" нужный нам файл, без глубокого анализа содержимого файла. Это легко проверить: возьмите файл с фотографией и переименуйте в test.txt, а затем в командной строке наберите `<полный путь к файлу>\test.txt`. В результате откроется текстовый редактор (блокнот или любой другой, который у вас назначен для файлов типа `*.txt` с мало понятным содержимым, там же фотография, а не текст. Можете еще поиграть с этим файлом меняя ему расширение произвольным образом и запуская программы, для которых он не предназначен.

Таким образом, имя файла не сообщает ни нам (человеку), ни программе ни какой полезной информации о содержании файла. А как-же тогда другие программы узнают свои файлы? - по внутренней структуре.

**2. Допустим мы знаем особенности структуры файла.**

Программы знают как устроены файлы, с которыми они умеют работать. Это означает, что вы можете любой программой попытаться открыть любой файл, но если программа не опознает знакомую внутреннюю структуру или найдет в ней ошибки, то она может отказаться открывать такой файл, сообщив о несовместимости форматов. Еще раз повторю, совместимость форматов не зависит от расширения файла. Это зависит только от расположения конкретных байтов в конкретном файле, требования к которому известны программе, которой вы пытаетесь этот файл открыть. А как же блокнот (notepad и все возможные вариации на тему)? Почему он открывает любые файлы? Да просто потому, что простой текст без форматирования (plain text) не имеет ни каких отличительных черт, это просто последовательность байт, которая не содержит ничего, даже указаний на кодировку символов.

Для широко используемых форматов в сети можно найти описания или даже стандарты, в которых описано, какие (по порядковым номерам) байты, за что в этом типе файлов отвечают.

При открытии произвольного файла, нужно сравнить структуру файла с ожидаемой известной структурой. Если ключевые особенности совпали, нужно проверить корректность опознанной структуры. И только после подтверждения корректности можно утверждать, что файл имеет конкретный тип и может быть открыт конкретной  программой.

Таким образом, опознать реальный тип файла можно только по его структуре. И чем более жестко заданы ограничения структуры на формат и расположение данных, тем менее вероятно ложное срабатывание.

---

Если файл записываете вы, и вы же потом собираетесь его читать, то позаботьтесь о том, чтобы ваша программа записывала и читала данные файла всегда в одном и том же порядке в случае бинарных файлов. Либо используйте характерные маркеры разметки, по аналогии с XML или JSON, которые позволяют использовать простой текст для хранения сложных объектов.

---

**Если нужно просто узнать что за файл такой вам подсунули:**

В *nix существует команда [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) (Спасибо [@avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp)), которая позволяет опознавать файлы на основе ряда тестов. Наиболее интересный из них - [magic](https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic).

Для Windows можно воспользоваться аналогичной, но, увы, сторонней программой, встроенных средств не предусмотрено. Например [TrID - File Identifier](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) для командной строки (спасибо [@firepro](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/216352/firepro))

Comment: Может стоит хотя бы упомянуть команду [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) из \*nix-ов

Comment: @avp хм, удобная штука, и почему в винде такого нет, надо будет написать для себя =) ничего сложного в принципе

Comment: Тогда не забудьте почитать и [man 5 magic](https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic)

Comment: @avp уже =) там же кросс-линки есть. поправьте если ошибаюсь - magic просто поиск заданных сигнатур в файлах, т.е. его в принципе можно обмануть если очень захочется, как и любой антивирус в принципе.

Comment: Обмануть можно всегда. magic это по сути правила, как описывать форматы файлов.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57868/discussion-between-rdorn-and-avp).

Comment: Для Windows кстати, давно есть приложение командной строки TrID, которое порядка 9000 типов файлов может определить и сказать из чего он состоит. http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html

Comment: @Firepro это сторонняя разработка, родной то утилиты нет. Но за ссылку спасибо, опробую.

Comment: Я бы более строго определил понятия "полное имя", "имя", "расширение" и "тип" и сделал бы бОльший акцент на искусственности понятия "расширение". И - признак типа может быть больше расширения (например, вполне стандартный, правда, не распознаваемый правильно, тип .FB2.ZIP).

Comment: @Akina так вроде получше стало